# Reading a text file gives access denied error -Tried giving permissions to folder as well

Tags: java

What I am trying to do here is read a text file from my system and print it's contents in java
I have also tried giving permissions to folder in which it is present please have a look at my code:

```
public class Rtree {

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
    //  ArrayList<String> st=new ArrayList<String>();

    try{    
        FileReader file=new FileReader("D://Qos Logs");
        //DataInputStream In=new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(file);
        String s;
        while((s =br.readLine()) !=null){
        //  text=
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        br.close();
    //  In.close();
    }   catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error:"+e.getMessage());

    }

}
}
```

Comment: What is your file name? I think  there is a mistake in your file path.

Comment: Please add stack trace and what about file permission?

Comment: @nirajPatel File Name is 20111123.txt

Comment: @kushagra i tried unsetting read-only permission to folder which contains the file,Still error comes access denied

Comment: Why dont you give full path including file name ?

Comment: @kushagra it gives below error then:            Error:D:\Qos Logs\20111123.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: find text file from : https://www.sendspace.com/file/b90wlf

Comment: Have  you tried once removing spaced from folder name ?

Comment: Yes i tried it also still can't access

Comment: Open Run Window and try pasting this : D:\QosLogs\20111123.txt and see is file opens or not. @k.sahni

Comment: No cannot access it shows:windows can't find that file

Comment: Your code tries to read a file named `Qos Logs` in the root of the  `d:` drive, not a file named `20111123.txt`. Please edit your question (instead of appending more and more comments) and clean it up. Provide the exact error (and stack trace), and don't tell us you are trying to read one file when your code tries to read another one.

Comment: There is some issue with the file, that is the reason why java is not able to read it , try same thing till folder name D:\Qos Logs @k.sahni

Comment: @Robert i had already tried specifying the full name wih the file name.txt This might be having problems since it's a log format text file , and i am at one time trying to access one file only

Comment: I tried with different fresh file ,It is working Ok-Wonder what is the problem with that file? : Thanks For Your Help mate

Comment: The issue will be the file extension. Try this with older file once
FileReader file=new FileReader("D:\folder\ 20111123.txt.txt"); @k.sahni

Comment: Tried that too FileReader file=new FileReader("D:\folder\ 20111123.txt.txt");  still error is coming please go to  https://www.sendspace.com/file/b90wlf  to find that file if you could help

Comment: @kmittal i tried with D:\folder\ 20111123.log it is working now ,The  only difference is log file is same as text file but extension is different ...Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of reading the file, but I'll show the simplest one. Use `\\` slash when you give the full path of your file. Separating the folders and your file name by `\\`.

Try doing this in your code :

```
 FileReader file=new FileReader("D:\\path of your file\\ 20111123.txt");
```

Comment: Error:D:\Qos Logs\20111123.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Did you try  `\\\` in between your file path

Comment: Can you add the error in the question description with what you just tried?

Comment: Error is:Error:D:\QosLogs\20111123.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: try reading some other `txt` file on your computer. Maybe it's not the correct path or maybe file does not exist in your system, I don't know. But his is how you will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can read data using File and Scanner class simply pass the address of the file in File class Constructor and used the object of a class in your Scanner constructor next code in front of you.

```
try {
      File file = new File("Path of your file include file name with extension like  C:\\Users\\kashi\\Desktop\\DNA.txt");

      if(file.exists()){
          System.out.println("yes");
          Scanner readFile = new Scanner(file);
          if(file.canRead()){
              System.out.println("yes you can read it");

              if(readFile.hasNext()){
                  System.out.println(readFile.nextLine());
              }

          }
      }else {
          System.out.println("No");
      }
}catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```